# Как реализовать полнотекстовый поиск по pdf файлам на своем сайте?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, полнотекстовый-поиск

Есть сайт, на который контент-менеджеры загружают файлы в формате pdf(спецификации различного оборудования, инструкции по эксплуатации, обзорное сравнение разных моделей). Заказчик хочет, поисковую строку с возможностью ввести произвольный запрос и поисковыми подсказками. Существуют ли готовые решения? Какие инструменты и библиотеки можно использовать для реализации данного функционала?

Comment: pdf векторный фаил, функционал будет сложным, необходим индекс, прогонять через распознование фаил и распознанный текст ложить в б.д. и потом по нему искать.

Comment: Можете попробовать https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

Comment: @Naumov что за ерунда. Векторный пдф только у криворуких создателей, у нормальных в пдф нормальный текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готовых решений нет.

Вам необходимо удостоверится что менеджеры загружают PDF файлы в которых текст размещен именно как текст, а не часть изображения (слова можно выделить и скопировать).

Далее вам потребуется выбрать класс или библиотеку для перевода PDF в текст. 
Самое простое: https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

```
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;
$pdftext = Pdf::getText('book.pdf'); // Сохраняем в переменную текст PDF
```

Если знания глубоки и вы в состоянии дорабатывать код под свою задачу можно попробовать вот такой класс: https://pastebin.com/hRviHKp1

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$pdf = new PDF2Text();
$pdf->setFilename('book.pdf');
$pdf->decodePDF();
$pdftext = $pdf->output(); // Сохраняем в переменную текст PDF
```

Выше рекомендовали Xpdf - его тоже можно использовать.

Дальше вам нужно при загрузке конвертировать таким образом каждый файл в текст и обрабатывать в зависимости от потребностей (сохранять текст в mySQL, добавлять связи с статьями/товарами сайта и т.д.)

Правильнее всего написать для этих целей отдельный обработчик, который будет запускаться при загрузке файла.

Касательно поиска - учитывая что у вас битрикс, нужно будет продумать, как заносить эти данные в базу данных, чтобы они попадали в SEARCHABLE_CONTENT и были доступны для стандартного поиска/фильтра. Можно так же написать свой собственный поиск (Если будет принято решение хранить данные текста PDF отдельно от битрикс для оптимизации нагрузок).

Answer (score 0):

Xpdf - http://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html
может вам помочь

тут примеры

https://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php

https://php.livejournal.com/295413.html